# ECMAScript 6 promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'd like understand promises, but I have problem.

```
function commentFirst() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('first');
      resolve('value');
    }, 1500);
  });
}

commentFirst().then((val) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(val + ' 1')                   
  }, 2000);

  return val;
}).then((val1) => console.log(val1 + ' 2'));
```

I want get output like this:

```
first
value 1
value 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You *always* need to return a promise when you're doing something asynchronous. Also in `then` callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

In the second `.then`, you are doing a setTimeout without any promise, so it will execute and return immediately, even before the setTimeout executes. I've added a promise such that when the setTimeout executes, it will resolve the promise, and then continue executing the order you need.

```
function commentFirst() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('first');
      resolve("value");
    }, 1500);
  });
}

commentFirst()
  .then((val) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(val + ' 1')
        resolve(val);
      }, 2000);
    })
  })
  .then((val1) => console.log(val1 + ' 2'));
```

[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbNarv?editors=001)

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your code by creating multiple promise, to make your code more reusable.

So, you will be able to **chain your promise**.

But, you should see the [**Promise.all()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method which allow you to returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved.

You can decalre two function which will return some promise :

```
function first(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('first');
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function commentFirst(id){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('value ' + id);
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Then, you've got two options :

- Option 1 : Perform a chaining promise
- Option 2 : Use the `Promise.all()` method

**Option 1 : chaining**

```
first().then((data) => {
  //Log first
  console.log(data);
  //Return promise to print value 1
  return commentFirst(1);
}).then((data) => {
  //Log value 1
  console.log(data);
  //Return promise to print value 2
  return commentFirst(2);
}).then((data) => {
  //log value 2
  console.log(data);
});
```

**Option 2 : Promise.all()**

```
Promise.all([first(), commentFirst(1), commentFirst(2)]).then((data) => {
  data.forEach((elm) => console.log(elm));
});
```

As you can see, **option 2** is shorter than **option 1**. In fact, the **.all()** method is used to handle multiple promise, and return a single promise with all the results.